# what is the content of or type of django Queyset all method

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-templates

Assume that we have a model called Person.

```
class Person(models.Model)
    name = CharFiled(max_length=250)
    place = CharField(max_length=250)
```

I the view when we call Person.object.all(), then what exactly is the output.

Is that a list of dictionary items.

I need to manually (hard code) create an object which would be exactly similar to the return type of Person.object.all() and I want to pass that manually created object in view to template for display. My template currently accepts the Person.object.all() and process it and display values and I need my template to accept the manually created object in same way which is the purpose of creating similar object.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create class PersonManager:

```
class PersonManager(Manager):

    def specify_names(self):
        """ All peoples with name contan `J` letter """
        return self.filter(name__icontans='j')



class Person(models.Model)
    name = CharFiled(max_length=250)
    place = CharField(max_length=250)

    objects = PersonManager()
```

In view:

`my_persons = Person.object.specify_names()`

Answer (score 0):

The `all()` method returns `QuerySet`. Until you evaluate it, it wont do any database hits (by evaluating i mean - slicing, pickling, caching, repr, len, list, bool). When you iterate over `QuerySet` it will take advantage of your database to load data and instantiate model objects only as you need them.

See:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated

If you want to mock querysets there is a nice package to do just that:

https://github.com/dcramer/mock-django